# Ajax call with Flask

Tags: jquery, ajax, flask

I am trying to call a server-side script that is located in a file right off the root directory of my website. I can get to my javascript file fine, and I get to a point in the script where I call:

`var posting = $.post('/featurize', $('#input'))`

this is my python script (called script.py):

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/featurize', methods=['POST'])
def featurize():
    --code here, getting output--
    return jsonify({'output': output});
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

However, I'm returned a posting.fail each time I call it, and when I debug in my browser console, I get this:
`http://mywebsite.com/featurize 404 (Not Found)`

Therefore, my @app.route('/featurize') must not be working for some reason. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

(I'm also using jquery 1.11.1 from Google)

Comment: Do you see request in flask log/console? Seems that it is not problem with routing, but with flask deploy.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I'm trying to set up the log so I can see if there's anything wrong there.